# find everything between characters. javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get this Html inside certain characters:

i only want HTML starting from .. I'm new to regular expression but some how managed to match the result including the "{slider_images}" & "{/slider_images}" but I want only things that are between them.

I tried this:

example content:
HTML

```
{slider_images}<div class="slide_images">..other codes here..</div>{/slide_images}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.slides').each(function(){
    slide_text = $(this).html();
    slide_content = slide_text.match(/[\{slider_images\}](.*[^\{\/slider_images\}])/g);
    alert(slide_content);
});
```

The output includes the characters and tabs are replaced with commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
slide_content = slide_text.match(/\{slider_images}([\s\S]*)\{\/slider_images}/i);
```

And grab captured group #1 using:

```
slide_content[1];
```

Comment: You [can't extract](https://tio.run/##JYxBDsIgEEX3PcWkqxJiG9bEuPAC7q0LAhOKoWBgNO1JeqAejKJu/3vvP9VHZZ3ci04hGizFI0FCiwucYRh5NxrO9u0yWNl8ES1UQetAzfDOLli4ci4EqGDgttIUA3Cxb@3fTpirXZt@VqSn7nfMZKNjyNFj76OtW76LB5OlHA) 1st capturing group using `String.match(RegExp)[1]`!

Comment: Don't use global flag in your regex. Use: `regex = /\+(\d+)×?/`